# number of ssh sessions allowed from a server

Tags: ssh, parallel-ssh

I will try to be very specific to the question, please pardon my language if not clear.

Say i have a Unix system 'A', from where I want to ssh into some other servers in parallel and do some task. How will I know how many parallel ssh are allowed on 'A' server ?

Answer (score 3):

For your particular case, it depends on some factors (Hardware and OS).
You have to check the `limits` set on your machine (you didn't say anything about the architecture).
Try to check `ulimit -a` and take a look, for example, at limits about `open files` parameter (it is even relative to the number of open sockets).
These are limits set for user; you can take a look at `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` (if you're on an Ubuntu machine) to look at system-wide setting about that parameter.

Other than limits set into the system and limits of your hardware (RAM saturation, etc.), there's no explicit limitation set by SSH Client (as I know).

If you configure limits that you need on your client machine, but you cannot have more SSH connections to the same Server, try to customize followind parameter on the server side `sshd`,

You can customize the parallel sessions allowed from inside your configuration file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, using as much sessions as you need.

The following parameter should do the trick:

> **MaxSessions**
>                Specifies the maximum number of open shell, login or subsystem
>                (e.g. sftp) sessions permitted per network connection.  Multiple
>                sessions may be established by clients that support connection
>                multiplexing.  Setting MaxSessions to 1 will effectively disable
>                session multiplexing, whereas setting it to 0 will prevent all
>                shell, login and subsystem sessions while still permitting for-
>                warding.  The default is 10.

Comment: Isn't the question about SSH client sessions?

Comment: You're right. I've confused the role role of machines involved in the request. Thank you ;) ! Answer updated

Comment: Other factors are probably the number of network interfaces, IP addresses, and the current availability of ephemeral client ports.

Comment: MaxSessions specifically says it controls the number of sessions _per network connection_, those multiplexed over one TCP stream. It doesn't do anything about distinct connections, which is what you get by default when running `ssh somehost` and another `ssh somehost`.

Answer (score 2):

There are no limits specifically for `ssh`. There might be limits on the total number of processes you are permitted on the system 'A' but in my experience this is rare